How to add spacing to JavaScript todo list webapp overlapping on top of each other?
I'm trying to achieve this where each task isn't overlapping on top of each other, but I'm having a headache trying to figure out how to do that, how could I achieve that?, so that every time I create a new task, it is not overlapping!: 
Here's how it currently looks! the task name, date, and day are overlapping on top of each other.

Here's the code


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  const darkModeToggle = document.getElementById("darkmode-toggle");
  const body = document.body;
  const tasks = []; // Array to store tasks

  darkModeToggle.addEventListener("change", function () {
    if (this.checked) {
      body.classList.add("dark-mode");
    } else {
      body.classList.remove("dark-mode");
    }
  });

  const newButton = document.getElementById("new-btn");
  const wholeContainer = document.querySelector(".whole-container");
  const submitButton = document.querySelector(".submit-btn");
  const taskNameInput = document.getElementById("taskName");
  const taskDayInput = document.getElementById("taskDay");
  const taskDateInput = document.getElementById("taskDate");
  const taskList = document.querySelector(".task-list");

  function showWholeContainer() {
    wholeContainer.style.visibility = "visible";
    wholeContainer.style.opacity = "1";
    newButton.disabled = true;
    document.addEventListener("click", clickOutsideHandler);
  }

  function hideWholeContainer() {
    wholeContainer.style.opacity = "0";
    setTimeout(() => {
      wholeContainer.style.visibility = "hidden";
      newButton.disabled = false;
    }, 200);
  }

  function clickOutsideHandler(event) {
    if (!wholeContainer.contains(event.target) && event.target !== newButton) {
      hideWholeContainer();
    }
  }

  function resetForm() {
    taskNameInput.value = "";
    taskDayInput.value = "";
    taskDateInput.value = "";
  }

  function showTaskList() {
    const wholeContainerTwo = document.querySelector(".whole-container-two");
    wholeContainerTwo.style.visibility = "visible";
    wholeContainerTwo.style.opacity = "1";
  }

  function validateForm() {
    if (
      taskNameInput.value.trim() === "" ||
      taskDayInput.value.trim() === "" ||
      taskDateInput.value.trim() === ""
    ) {
      alert("Please fill out task name, day, and task date fields.");
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  newButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    showWholeContainer();
  });

  submitButton.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (validateForm()) {
      const task = {
        name: taskNameInput.value,
        day: taskDayInput.value,
        date: taskDateInput.value,
        completed: false,
      };
      tasks.push(task); // Add task to array
      renderTasks(); // Render updated tasks
      resetForm();
      showTaskList();
      hideWholeContainer();
    }
  });

  function renderTasks() {
    taskList.innerHTML = ""; // Clear existing tasks
    tasks.forEach((task, index) => {
      const taskItem = document.createElement("li");
      taskItem.classList.add("todo-item");
      taskItem.innerHTML = `
        <input type="checkbox" id="check-mark-${index}" class="checkbox-input">
        <label for="check-mark-${index}" class="checkmark-label">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check"></i>
        </label>
        <span class="task-day-list">${task.day}</span>
        <span class="task-date-list">${task.date}</span>
        <span class="task-name-list">${task.name}</span>
      `;
      taskList.appendChild(taskItem);

      const checkbox = taskItem.querySelector(`#check-mark-${index}`);
      const taskName = taskItem.querySelector(".task-name-list");

      checkbox.addEventListener("change", function () {
        if (this.checked) {
          taskName.classList.add("checked");
        } else {
          taskName.classList.remove("checked");
        }
      });
    });
  }

  hideWholeContainer();
});
header {
  position: fixed;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  background-color: #f1ebdd;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

/*header*/

.nav-container {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
  z-index: 2;
}

.nav-container button {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border-color: transparent;
  background-color: #58585a;
  color: #f1ebdd;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-container button:hover {
  background-color: #f1ebdd;
  color: #58585a;
  transition: 0.6ms;
}

.user-btn {
  margin: 45px 0px 0px 50px;
  padding: 25px 80px 25px 80px;
}

.mylist-btn {
  margin: 45px 0px 0px 50px;
  padding: 10% 25% 10% 26%;
}

.categories-btn {
  margin: 45px 0px 0px 50px;
  padding: 10% 20% 10% 21%;
}

.calendar-btn {
  margin: 45px 0px 0px 50px;
  padding: 10% 23% 10% 25%;
}

.settings-btn {
  margin: 45px 0px 0px 50px;
  padding: 10% 23% 10% 26%;
}

.about-btn {
  margin: 45px 0px 0px 50px;
  padding: 10% 23% 10% 23%;
}

/*Day/night Switch*/

.label-data {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 775px 0% 0% 50px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 200px;
  background-color: #f1ebdd;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 2;
}

.label-data:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  border-radius: 180px;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(255, 170, 58), #d8a80b);
}

.input-data {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.input-data:checked + .label-data {
  background: #242424;
}

.input-data:checked + .label-data:after {
  left: 200px;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #a3a3a3, #353535);
}

.label-data,
.label-data:after {
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.label-data:active:after {
  width: 50px;
}

.label-data svg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 70px;
  top: 5px;
  z-index: 100;
}

.label-data svg.sun {
  left: 5px;
  fill: #f1ebdd;
  border-radius: 50px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.label-data svg.moon {
  left: 125px;
  fill: #333333;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.input-data:checked + .label-data svg.sun {
  fill: #242424;
}

.input-data:checked + .label-data svg.moon {
  fill: #f1ebdd;
}

.input-data:checked + .label-data + .background {
  background: #242424;
}

/*sidebar fixed background color*/

.sidebar-background h1 {
  position: fixed;
  padding: 40% 7% 10% 10%;
  margin: -1% 90% 0% 0%;
  background-color: #dbd8d3;
  z-index: 1;
}

/*to-do list app*/

.todo-container {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 70px 0px 0px 90%;
  z-index: 100;
}

.todo-container .new {
  padding: 3px 18px 3px 18px;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  color: #f1ebdd;
  background-color: #4eaabe;
  border-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.8s;
}

.todo-container .new:hover {
  padding: 5px 25px 5px 25px;
  transition: 0.8s;
}

/*to-do list app window pop up*/

.whole-container {
  display: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0.8s ease, opacity 0.2s ease;
}

.hidden {
  /*JavaScript code*/
  display: none;
}

.window-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 150px 150px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: #dbd8d3;
  transition: 0.4s;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.window-wrapper .form-data {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: left;
  gap: 25px;
  width: 150%;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.form-data label {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #f1ebdd;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #58585a;
}

.form-data input {
  border-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 25px;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #58585a;
  background-color: #f1ebdd;
  outline-color: #58585a;
}

.form-data .submit-btn {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border-color: transparent;
  background-color: #58585a;
  color: #f1ebdd;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/*to-do list after window*/

.whole-container-two {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: visibility 0.8s ease, opacity 0.2s ease;
}

.task-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 177px 0% 0% 20%;
  padding: 0% 1% 0% 0%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: #4eaabe;
  z-index: -50;
}

.task-wrapper ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.task-list li {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 30px;
}

.todo-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.todo-item span {
  text-align: left;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.checkbox-input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.checkmark-label {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.fa-circle-check {
  margin: -8px 0px 0px -60px;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #f1ebdd;
  background-color: #f1ebdd;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.checkbox-input:checked + .checkmark-label .fa-circle-check {
  color: #ace464;
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.todo-item .task-date-list {
  position: absolute;
  margin: -60px 0% 0% -70px;
  padding: 5px 1% 5px 1%;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #bcb7af;
  z-index: -50;
}

.task-name-list {
  color: #f1ebdd;
}

.task-name-list.checked {
  text-decoration-line: line-through;
}

.todo-item .task-day-list {
  position: absolute;
  margin: -100px 0% 0% -75px;
  padding: 5px 1% 5px 1%;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #58585a;
  z-index: -50;
}

/* Dark mode background colors */
.dark-mode {
  background-color: #242424;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.dark-mode .nav-container button {
  background-color: #242424;
  color: #f1ebdd;
}

.dark-mode .nav-container button:hover {
  background-color: #f1ebdd;
  color: #242424;
  transition: 0.6ms;
}

.dark-mode .input-data:checked + .label-data {
  background: #242424;
}

.dark-mode .input-data:checked + .label-data:after {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #6e46fd, #2f0ea5);
}

.dark-mode .input-data:checked + .label-data svg.sun {
  fill: #242424;
}

.dark-mode .input-data:checked + .label-data svg.moon {
  fill: #f1ebdd;
}

.dark-mode .sidebar-background h1 {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #6e46fd, #2f0ea5);
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.dark-mode .window-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 150px 150px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #6e46fd, #2f0ea5);
  transition: 0.4s;
  z-index: 300;
}

.dark-mode .form-data label {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #f1ebdd;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #242424;
}

.dark-mode .form-data input {
  border-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 25px;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #242424;
  background-color: #f1ebdd;
  outline-color: #242424;
}

.dark-mode .form-data .submit-btn {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border-color: transparent;
  background-color: #242424;
  color: #f1ebdd;
  cursor: pointer;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>MyList: Enhanced to-do list app</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/3ba961a955.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <!--Sidebar navigation-->
      <nav class="nav-container" role="button">
        <button type="button" class="user-btn">User</button>
        <button type="button" class="mylist-btn">My lists</button>
        <button type="button" class="categories-btn">Categories</button>
        <button type="button" class="calendar-btn">Calendar</button>
        <button type="button" class="settings-btn">Settings</button>
        <button type="button" class="about-btn">About us</button>
      </nav>
      <!--Day/night Switch-->
      <input class="input-data" type="checkbox" id="darkmode-toggle" />
      <label class="label-data" for="darkmode-toggle">
        <svg
          version="1.1"
          class="sun"
          viewBox="0 0 24 24"
          fill="none"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        >
          <g id="SVGRepo_bgCarrier" stroke-width="0"></g>
          <g
            id="SVGRepo_tracerCarrier"
            stroke-linecap="round"
            stroke-linejoin="round"
          ></g>
          <g id="SVGRepo_iconCarrier">
            <path
              d="M12 3V4M12 20V21M4 12H3M6.31412 6.31412L5.5 5.5M17.6859 6.31412L18.5 5.5M6.31412 17.69L5.5 18.5001M17.6859 17.69L18.5 18.5001M21 12H20M16 12C16 14.2091 14.2091 16 12 16C9.79086 16 8 14.2091 8 12C8 9.79086 9.79086 8 12 8C14.2091 8 16 9.79086 16 12Z"
              stroke="#f1ebdd"
              stroke-width="2"
              stroke-linecap="round"
              stroke-linejoin="round"
            ></path>
          </g>
        </svg>
        <svg
          version="1.1"
          class="moon"
          viewBox="0 0 24 24"
          fill="none"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        >
          <g id="SVGRepo_bgCarrier1" stroke-width="0"></g>
          <g
            id="SVGRepo_tracerCarrier2"
            stroke-linecap="round"
            stroke-linejoin="round"
          ></g>
          <g id="SVGRepo_iconCarrier3">
            <path
              d="M3.32031 11.6835C3.32031 16.6541 7.34975 20.6835 12.3203 20.6835C16.1075 20.6835 19.3483 18.3443 20.6768 15.032C19.6402 15.4486 18.5059 15.6834 17.3203 15.6834C12.3497 15.6834 8.32031 11.654 8.32031 6.68342C8.32031 5.50338 8.55165 4.36259 8.96453 3.32996C5.65605 4.66028 3.32031 7.89912 3.32031 11.6835Z"
              stroke="#f1f1f1f1"
              stroke-width="0"
              stroke-linecap="round"
              stroke-linejoin="round"
            ></path>
          </g>
        </svg>
      </label>
      <!--sidebar fixed background color-->
      <div class="sidebar-background">
        <h1></h1>
      </div>
    </header>
    <!--to-do list app-->
    <div class="todo-container">
      <button type="button" class="new" id="new-btn">New</button>
    </div>
    <!--to-do list app window pop up-->
    <div class="whole-container">
      <div class="window-wrapper">
        <form class="form-data">
          <label for="taskName">Task Name</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="taskName"
            name="taskName"
            placeholder="What's in your mind?"
          />
          <label for="taskDate">Task Date and Day</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="taskDate"
            name="taskDate"
            placeholder="Set a date for your task"
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            id="taskDay"
            name="taskDay"
            placeholder="Set a day for your task"
          />
          <button type="submit" class="submit-btn">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--to-do list after window-->
    <div class="whole-container-two">
      <div class="task-wrapper">
        <ul class="task-list">
          <li class="todo-item">
            <input type="checkbox" id="check-mark" class="checkbox-input" />
            <label for="check-mark" class="checkmark-label"
              ><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check"></i
            ></label>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>




There's a lot of position: absolute. From the docs "absolute - The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout" - This probably isn't what you really want.
